# is there any security risk to public publish dockerconfigjson

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I was reading the documentation about `kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson`
and I just have a question: Is there any security risk to public publish `dockerconfigjson`? For example:

```
    data:
  .dockerconfigjson: <base64>
```

Comment: I'd expect that to usually contain credentials to access your Docker registry...so yes, it'd be a significant security exposure to publish it?

Answer (score 2):

Posted community wiki answer for better visibility. Feel free to expand it.

---

As suggested by David Maze's comment:

> I'd expect that to usually contain credentials to access your Docker registry...so yes, it'd be a significant security exposure to publish it?

It's dangerous and not recommended because docker `config.json` imported to Kubernetes is mainly used [for keeping credentials used for pulling images](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/) from private registry.

Even if it's saved in base64 format as in [example from Kubernetes docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/#registry-secret-existing-credentials) (in your example too) it can be easily decoded:

*my-secret.yaml*

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: myregistrykey
  namespace: awesomeapps
data:
  .dockerconfigjson: UmVhbGx5IHJlYWxseSByZWVlZWVlZWVlZWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWxsbGxsbGxsbGxsbGxsbGxsbGxsbGxsbGxsbGxsbGx5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eSBsbGxsbGxsbGxsbGxsbG9vb29vb29vb29vb29vb29vb29vb29vb29vb25ubm5ubm5ubm5ubm5ubm5ubm5ubm5ubmdnZ2dnZ2dnZ2dnZ2dnZ2dnZ2cgYXV0aCBrZXlzCg==
type: kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson
```

Let's decode it:

```
user@shell:~/ $ cat my-secret.yaml | yq e '.data.".dockerconfigjson"' - | base64 -d
Really really reeeeeeeeeeaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaalllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy llllllllllllllooooooooooooooooooooooooooonnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnggggggggggggggggggg auth keys
```